# Energy functional continuous with respect of time $t$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, parabolic-pde

I am studying a paper of Liu Yacheng which named ["On potential wells and applications to semilinear hyperbolic equations and parabolic equations"](http://gongxue.cn/xiaoyuanwenhua/UploadFiles_5571/200510/20051013123234277.pdf) it considers a nonlinear parabolic equation
\begin{equation}
\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    u_{t}-\triangle u=f(u), & \hbox{$x\in\Omega,t>0$;} \\
    u(x,0)=u_{0}(x), & \hbox{$x\in\Omega$;} \\
    u(x,t)=0, & \hbox{$x\in\partial\Omega, t\geq 0$.}
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
where $f(u)=u|u|^{p-1}$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n (n\geq 3)$ is a bounded smooth domain, the constant $p$ satisfies $2<p+1\leq \frac{2n}{n-2}$. In the paper of Liu, he defined a weak solution $u(x,t)$ of above nonlinear parabolic equation which satisfy $u\in L^{\infty}(0,T;H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)), u_{t}\in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ for some $T>0$, and also defined a functional 
$$ I(u)=\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^{2}-\int_{\Omega}|u|^{p+1}dx. $$
I want to ask that: "**if $u\in L^{\infty}(0,T;H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)), u_{t}\in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ is a weak solution of above nonlinear parabolic equation, can we deduce that the functional $I(u)$ is a continuous function with respect $t$ ?"**

In the paper of L.E. Payne and D.H. Sattinger "[Saddle points and instability of nonlinear hyperbolic equaitons](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14gzwy_qv7_rMDdh2UuMyT5MyMUKGYjEt/view?usp=sharing)", it gave a positive answer of above question but without a complete proof (see Page 294). From the Holder's inequality and Sobolev embedding, I can only deduce that the functional $I(u)$ is Lipschitz continuous in $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, i.e.
$$ |I(u)-I(v)|\leq C\|u-v\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)},~~\forall u,v\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)  $$ for some positive $C>0$.

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much in advance!